# How to get notification of and read a resized window in C# for .NET Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize

My idea consists of having a window which has a set height and width as any other window does *at the beginning*, however, the user might find it necessary to resize this window for his or her comfort. In this window, I will have shapes and other things that resize in accord to the size and dimensions of the window.

How do I make sure that my program realises that the window has been resized and subsequently informs my functions or changes dimensions in the code it-self?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Form window = new Form();
void Main(string[] args)
{    
    window.Width = 1015;
    window.Height = 645;

    window.Text = "Grid";

    window.Paint += window_Paint;

    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `Form` has a resize event you can subscribe to. Also you can set size to autosize.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event `System.Windows.Forms.Form.SizeChanged` which you should hook up with your event handler in which you can process everything what depends on Form size. Alternative method is to override `OnSizeChanged` method in your derived form class. Let Visual Studio create template application for you as your code is far away from what will work. Examples are below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HandleSaizeChanged
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;
        }

        private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle data based on new Form size
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            // Handle data based on new Form size
        }
    }
}
```